# Filter on values of json object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a jsonb column:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id serial primary key,
  data jsonb
);

insert into test (data) values(
({"a" : 1,"b" : 2,"r1" : 2, "r2" : 5}),
({"a" : 3,"b" : 3,"r1" : 2, "r2" : 2,"r3" : 7}),
({"a" : 5,"b" : 1,"r1" : 1, "r2" : 5,"r4" : 2}),
({"a" : 2,"b" : 2,"r1" : 5, "r2" : 6,"r3" : 5,"r4" : 7}),
({"a" : 9,"b" : 2,"r1" : 9, "r2" : 1,"r3" : 5,"r5" : 2}));
```

Then I want to execute the following

```
select data 
from test 
where data->>'r1' = 2 or data->>'r2' = 2 or data->>'r3' = 2 or data->'r4' = 2 or data->>'r5' = 2;
```

Is there a more compact way to write this select?

Answer (score 0):

```
select data
from t
where '2' in (
    data ->> 'r1', data ->> 'r2', data ->> 'r3', data ->> 'r4', data ->> 'r5'
)
```

If the keys are known then a good option (apart from the highly recommended normalization) is to create a view to facilitate queries:

```
create view v as
select id,
    (data ->> 'a')::int as a,
    (data ->> 'b')::int as b,
    (data ->> 'r1')::int as r1,
    (data ->> 'r2')::int as r2,
    (data ->> 'r3')::int as r3,
    (data ->> 'r4')::int as r4,
    (data ->> 'r5')::int as r5
from t
;
```

Then it is just:

```
select *
from v
where 2 in (r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If r may be more than 5:

```
select data
  from testX
 where EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
            FROM generate_series(1, 5) AS i
           WHERE data->>('r' || i) = '2');
```